# AS3 Flash projector and Stage Video

Tags: flash

One of the shortcomings of desktop AIR is that Stage Video is not currently supported.

Can anyone tell me if Stage Video will work in a full screen flash projector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it should work and it will scale the video to fit, but keep the aspect ratio, so you'll get letterbox or curtains, depending on the video and screen display unless you allow for scaling.   Just add some code like the following for a callback:

```
    // Stretches video to fit
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

    // Crops video to fit - but fills the whole screen
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;

    // Shows video in true aspect ratio with no scaling or cropping
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NONE;
    // and
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;



    private function fsBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    }
```